# ObjectMapper with Custom class loader

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind, jackson2

We get some json string which needs to be converted into instance of a class which is part of some third party jar (which will be downloaded on the fly) which is not present in the class path.

and problem here is

We get below kind of Json

```
{
     "a" :{
     "nameType":"firstNameType"
     },
     "b":{
     "nameType":"lastNameType"
     }
  }
```

And java classes class structure in jar is as follows

```java
    class A{

    private String nameType;

    // getters and setters are avaiable
    }

    class B{

    private A a;

    private A b;

    // getters and setters
    }
```

when we de-serialize above json to class B, value present in "b.b.nameType" is "firstNameType" instead of "lastNameType".

below is the code snippet.

```java
    ClassLoader classLoader = TestClass.class.getClassLoader();
        ClassLoader loader =
                    new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new 
        File("/Users/asdasd3414234d/Downloads/Default" +
                            ".jar").toURI().toURL() }, classLoader);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            TypeFactory typeFactory = 
        TypeFactory.defaultInstance().withClassLoader(loader);
            objectMapper.setTypeFactory(typeFactory);

      objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, 
         false);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
       Object obj =  objectMapper.readValue(content,Class.forName("defaulttermlibrary.AmlTransaction",true,loader));
        System.out.println(obj);
```

could some one please help me

Comment: Your question hints at several things that seem to be missing: "class structure in jar is as follows", "below is the code snippet" ...

Comment: Where is the code snippet? @KarunakarReddyL

Comment: it was missing, I added now @Pie

Comment: But `b.a.nameType` path points to `firstNameType` in `JSON`, so it works properly. Why do you expect `lastNameType` there?

Comment: sorry @MichałZiober, I mentioned it wrongly, it `b.b.nameType` should be `lastNameType` but is it is `firstNameType`